# How to send Department ID and password to Canon iR / 3235 printer in code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, printing

Our client has a Canon iR/3235 PCL5 printer that they want our asp.net mvc web application to print to.  But the printer requires a department id and password interactively.

Is there a way to set the id and password in code with the application when printing to it?

Comment: there's no such thing as "C#.NET".

Comment: @John: thanks for the clarification.  I meant implementing it in .net using C#.  I can see how the wording could be misleading.  Although, I'm pretty sure anybody who's worked in .net would know what I meant.

Comment: I've worked in .NET since day "0", and I thought it was possible you were one of the several developers I've met who believe there is something named "C#.NET", since they know there's a "VB.NET".

Comment: @John: I see what you mean.  That makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

How is the print job sent. If the browser is doing the print, the **client** needs to do this in the browsers Print options.

The hard-core solution is to see what data the printer driver is sending to the printer, nad replicate that in your app.

However when Canon changes the driver, you are back to square one.

A last option is to see if the printer allows printing via FTP upload. Sometimes you can setup a userid /password to a specific's department's print queue. However in those circumstances you need to change the print data to PDF(easy) or PCL (never seen it yet). Also your ASP.net server needs to the printer, so if this is will **only**work if the application is an intra-net(internal) application

Comment: @gonsalv: thanks for your inputs.  Doesn't look like there is a concrete solution without Canon providing some sort of API.